# Haskell - Result of a program

Tags: haskell, trace

I've started studying Haskell a while ago and during my exams I was asked to answer what cost function would return if it was called but I couldn't understand which steps would occur. I'm sitting the exams again but I couldn't manage to understand the way I should solve this type of programs.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
cost = n(twice, inc, 3)
n(h,s,x) = if (x<1) then (h s x) else n(h, (h s), x-1)
inc x = x+1
twice n a = n (n a)
```

Comment: Simple. Take a sheet of paper, a pencil, and then just do text substitution of the arguments.

Comment: I've tried but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I had the same problem with prolog and by using trace mode I managed to understand it. With haskell I can't without at least an example...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type signatures would really go a long way here.  Let's start with the simplest one, `inc`:

```
inc :: Num a => a -> a
inc x = x + 1
```

This is easy to derive because `+ 1` has type `Num a => a -> a`, and you can check this in GHCi with `:type (+1)`.  Next, let's look at the function `twice`.  It's obvious that the `n` passed in has to be a function, since it's applied to both `a` and `n a`.  Because it's applied to `n a` and `a`, both of these expressions must have the same type, and `n` must have only one parameter, so we can say that `twice` has the type

```
twice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
twice n a = n (n a)
```

Now we can figure out `n`.  It takes a tuple `(h, s, x)` as an argument and is called recursively.  `h` has to be a function of two arguments, since it's applied to `s` and `x`, and `s` is unknown without more context.  `x` has to be both a `Num a => a` and an `Ord a => a` due to its use with `< 1` and `-1`, so we can write the signature as

```
n :: (Num a, Ord a) => (b -> a -> c, b, a) -> c
n (h, s, x) = if x < 1 then h s x else n (h, h s, x - 1)
```

Notice that I removed some unnecessary parens here.  Finally, we can figure out the type of `cost`, which is simply `n`'s return type:

```
cost :: (Num a, Ord a) => a
cost = n (twice, inc, 3)
```

But what would this return?  For starters, it's re-write `n`'s definition but with `twice`, `inc`, and `3` substituted in:

```
if 3 < 1
    then twice inc 3
    else n (twice, twice inc, 3 - 1)
```

Obviously `3 < 1` is false, so let's reduce `n (twice, twice inc, 3 - 1)`:

```
if 2 < 1
    then twice (twice inc) 2
    else n (twice, twice (twice inc), 2 - 1)
```

Same story here, `2 < 1` is false, so let's continue to reduce:

```
if 1 < 1
    then twice (twice (twice inc)) 1
    else n (twice, twice (twice (twice inc)), 1 - 1)
```

Nothing new on this step, one more try:

```
if 0 < 1
    then twice (twice (twice (twice inc))) 0
    else n (twice, twice (twice (twice (twice inc))), 0 - 1)
```

Here we have `0 < 1`, so we then choose the branch of `twice (twice (twice (twice inc))) 2`.  To solve this, just plug in `inc` and `0` into the definition of `twice`:

```
twice (twice (twice (twice inc))) 0
           = twice (twice (twice (inc . inc))) 0
           = twice (twice (inc . inc . inc . inc)) 0
           = twice (inc . inc . inc . inc . inc . inc . inc . inc) 0
           = (inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc) 0
           = 16
```

And we now can't reduce this expression any more!  So the entire chain of reductions is

```
cost = n (twice, inc, 3)
     = if 3 < 1
           then twice inc 3
           else n (twice, twice inc, 3 - 1)
     = n (twice, twice inc, 2)
     = if 2 < 1
           then twice (twice inc) 2
           else n (twice, twice (twice inc), 2 - 1)
     = n (twice, twice (twice inc), 1)
     = if 1 < 1
           then twice (twice (twice inc)) 1
           else n (twice, twice (twice (twice inc)), 1 - 1)
     = n (twice, twice (twice (twice inc)), 0)
     = if 0 < 1
           then twice (twice (twice (twice inc))) 0
           else n (twice, twice (twice (twice (twice inc))), 0 - 1)
     = twice (twice (twice (twice inc))) 0
     = inc (inc 0)
     = inc (0 + 1)
     = (inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc.inc) 0
     = 16
```

(To keep things readable I've used `twice f = f . f` instead of `twice f x = f (f x)`, but these definitions are equivalent)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. The right value is 16 though, I think it's because you forgot that second parameter is (h s). Your steps really helped me though :)

Comment: It's `else n (twice, (twice inc), 3 - 1)` etc. So in the last call you have `h (h 0)` where `h = (+8)`.

Comment: @Nick Ah, yes, you're correct, this is what I get for not running the code before posting it.  Good catch, and luckily I think this helped to demonstrate how to follow through this code by me inadvertently having an error in it.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: One last question. We say that twice has 2 parameters. By calling twice (twice inc) 0 for example, can you explain how the first parameter of twice ( I mean twice inc) is being calculated? I cannot follow this step only.

Comment: So another way to think of the function `twice` is as a function of a single argument that returns a new function (technically true of all functions in Haskell that have more than 1 arguments).  So its type would be `twice :: (a -> a) -> (a -> a)`. This is what is known as _higher order functions_. Since `twice inc` is a function, then `twice (twice inc)` is also a function. This is more obvious if you rewrite the definition as the equivalent `twice f = \x -> f (f x)`. So now if you plug in `inc` for `f` and reduce that expression, then repeat for `twice (twice inc)`, you should get the answer